# MySQL GROUPED BY/ORDER BY with XOR

Tags: mysql

I have a table "staff" with column name, relation clients and relation category.

```
id | Name    | client_id | category
1  | Test 1  | 0         | 22
2  | Test 2  | 2         | 22
3  | Test 3  | 3         | 22
4  | Test 4  | 5         | 22
5  | Test 11 | 0         | 25
6  | Test 22 | 2         | 25
7  | Test 33 | 3         | 25
8  | Test 44 | 5         | 25
9  | Test    | 0         | 27
```

My Question is:

How can I select a list of entries grouped by "category_id" with client_id=0 or client_id=5.

So I need this 3 entries:

```
 4  | Test 4  | 5         | 22
 8  | Test 44 | 5         | 25
 9  | Test    | 0         | 27
```

This one dosn't work

```
SELECT * from staff WHERE (staff.client_id = 0 XOR staff.client_id = 5) grouped by category_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query chekc if a category has 0 or 5 and selects the highest number.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `Name` VARCHAR(7),
>   `client_id` INTEGER,
>   `category` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `Name`, `client_id`, `category`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Test 1', '0', '22'),
>   ('2', 'Test 2', '2', '22'),
>   ('3', 'Test 3', '3', '22'),
>   ('4', 'Test 4', '5', '22'),
>   ('5', 'Test 11', '0', '25'),
>   ('6', 'Test 22', '2', '25'),
>   ('7', 'Test 33', '3', '25'),
>   ('8', 'Test 44', '5', '25'),
>   ('9', 'Test', '0', '27');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>   * 
> FROM 
>   table1 
> WHERE 
>   ( `client_id` ,`category`) IN (SELECT MAX(`client_id`), `category` 
>                                   FROM table1  WHERE `client_id` IN (0,5) GROUP BY `category`)
> ```
>
> ```
> id | Name    | client_id | category
> -: | :------ | --------: | -------:
>  4 | Test 4  |         5 |       22
>  8 | Test 44 |         5 |       25
>  9 | Test    |         0 |       27
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7155a2cc0fd3a401752b788709d0d1df)*